# Best practice to query the performance state of the mongo

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongohq

I'm interested in the best practice to query the performance state of the mongo cluster (on mongohq) using a ruby script.
I would like to build some ruby script that checks if the mongo is idle (or near idle) and if so, start to do some work (lots of queries and updates) on it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest instead of writing this yourself to have a look at MMS. MongoHQ supports this for their dedicated database plans. See https://mms.10gen.com/docs/faq for information.

If you *really* want to do this yourself, you need to call the [serverStatus](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/serverStatus+Command) command.

Answer (score 0):

Dru:

Also, there are some additional tools that MongoHQ can make available to you. Please drop the team a note and they can give you some things to try out. But yes, as was stated above, MMS is a good solution as well.

Jason
MongoHQ